Is there a way to extract the part of string in R
For this I want to get the string immediately after D:\. Any thought?
library(stringr)
str_extract("D:\Directory A\File.txt", "Directory A")

I get

Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string (<input>:1:17)



the problem is the single "\" symbols, that is a special character that should be scaped. This string should be "D:\\Directory A\\File.txt". That way it would work.

Well, unfortunately that's how windows paths look like

You might want to check the output of cat("D:\\Directory A\\File.txt)") . BTW,
"D:/Directory A/File.txt" is also perfectly valid Windows path, unless you you have to deal with pre-XP installations.

If you use getwd() you'll see the path the / instead of  \\, replace them and you'll be good to go.

You can use the r"(...)" syntax to enter windows file paths like this.
str_extract(r"(D:\Directory A\File.txt)", "Directory A")

OR replace \ with /
library(stringr)
str_extract("D:/Directory A/File.txt", "Directory A")

OR replace \ with \\
library(stringr)
str_extract("D:\\Directory A\\File.txt", "Directory A")


Wow this works! How can this be made more general to extract any word after the D:\

str_extract(r"(D:\Directory A\File.txt)", r"((?<=D:\\)\w+)") will get the next word. str_extract(r"(D:\Directory A\subdir b\File.txt)", r"((?<=D:\\).+?(?=\\))") will get everything until the next backslash (i.e. the folder name)

piggybacking on shaun_m 's answer, we can split by the delimiter and take the second section (i.e. first folder, the first section being the drive identifier):
library(stringr)

#Generalised first folder extraction:
str_split(r"(D:\Directory A\File.txt)", "\\\\")[[1]][2]
str_split("D:/Directory B/File.txt", pattern = "/")[[1]][2]
str_split("D:\\Directory C\\File.txt", "\\\\")[[1]][2]

return:
[1] "Directory A"
[1] "Directory B"
[1] "Directory C"

Or more generally still, and avoiding the need for the first subsetting [1] we can use str_split_i which puts the i'th  element, as well as using a single regex for either \ or / "\\\\|/":
sapply(c(r"(D:\Directory A\File.txt)", "D:/Directory B/File.txt", "D:\\Directory C\\File.txt"),
       \(x) { str_split_i(x, "\\\\|/", 2)})

gives
D:\\Directory A\\File.txt   D:/Directory B/File.txt D:\\Directory C\\File.txt 
            "Directory A"             "Directory B"             "Directory C"

Explanation for \\\\ - we  want the regex to look for \.  This is an escape character, so needs to be escaped: \\.  Unfortunately, it's also an escape character in R (as well as regex) so R will parse the string "\\" and just pass \ to the regex - if we want it to pass \\ then both the backslashes must be escaped: "\\\\" -> \\ finds "\"
